# why this code is not working?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

```
#! /bin/ksh
awk -F':' '{
if( match($0,":server:APBS") )
{
 print x;
 x=$0;
}
}' iws_config4.dat
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't a useful description of your problem.  What does it do?  What did you expect it to do?  What output/errors do you get?  What is in `iws_config4.dat`?

Comment: iam not getting any output. i want to print the line before greped.

Comment: you should edit your question to make it comprehensible, rather than adding comments.  You've been around SO long enough to have learned some of the basics of how to process questions.

Comment: Perhaps because you didn't copy this properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829177/how-do-i-output-the-previous-line-of-a-file-after-searching-for-a-specific-line/4834742#4834742

Comment: Does your input file have empty lines between the lines you're interested in (which *seems* to be the case in your previous question)? If so, you'll need to filter them out in one of various possible ways.

Answer (score 5):

You write your program in native `awk` as:

```
awk -F':' '/:server:APBS/ { print x; x=$0; }' iws_config4.dat
```

An `awk` program consists of patterns and the actions to take when those patterns match.  What you wrote is tantamount to abusing the built-in facilities of `awk`.

Given that you're only interested in `$0`, the field separator is redundant, so the `-F':'` argument could go.

What your program does is:

- read a line.
- if it matches the pattern

  - print the last line that matched
  - save the current line

So, if your input contains one match, you see nothing output (or, more precisely, a blank line).  If your input contains two matches, you see the first; if three, the first two; and so on.

---

Given the desire to emulate '`grep -B1 :server:APBS iws_config4.dat`', you can do:

```
awk '/:server:APBS/ { print old }
     { old = $0 }' iws_config4.dat
```

If the line matches, print the old saved line.
Regardless, store the current line as the (new) old saved line.

It probably can all be flattened onto one line.  It is crucial that the pattern match precede the unconditional save.

---

Given the script `k.awk` and data file `iws_config4.dat` shown, I get the output I expect.  What do you get?  What do you expect?

```
$ cat iws_config4.dat
One line of text followed by the marker
:server:APBS blah blah bah 1
:server:APBS blah blah bah 2
More text
     Blah blah blah
$ cat k.awk
awk '/:server:APBS/ { print old }
     { old = $0 }' iws_config4.dat
$ sh k.awk
One line of text followed by the marker
:server:APBS blah blah bah 1
$
```

---

If blank lines could be the trouble, only save non-blank lines:

```
awk '/:server:APBS/ { print old }
     /[^ ]/         { old = $0  }' iws_config4.dat
```

The second line now is only active on lines that contain at least one non-blank character, so only those lines will be saved.

Comment: @suvitha: If your input file has blank lines before the :Server:APBS lines, as per your question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4829177/78845), then you will get blank lines as output. Is that what you mean by "no output"?